# why generic class can extend a type shape?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript, just a question on a generic classes that extends type shape, below is some example code:

```
class DataCollection<T extends { name: string }> {
   ...
}
```

and it is valid code, it seems that a class can extend a type sharp, but it is not true, if we code like:

```
type Person = {
   name: string
}

class DataCollection extends Person {   // invalid code
   ...
}
```

it is not valid so class cannot extend a type sharp.

And we can only treat type `Person` as an interface and code in this way:

```
type Person = {
   name: string
}

class DataCollection implements Person {   //valid code
   ...
}
```

which means, it is more sensible to use the generic class as:

```
class DataCollection<T implements { name: string }> {
   ...
}
```

so why generic class can only extend a type shape but not implement a type shape?

Comment: You've mixed some concepts here.. `T extends { name: string }` is generic type parameter constraint. And it requires `T` to have `name` property of type `string`. E.g. `new DataCollection<Person>()` is valid, but `new DataCollection<{ foo: boolean }>()` is not. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints

Comment: @AlekseyL. so why we have to use 'extends' but not 'implements'

Comment: Again, you're mixing not related things. `class DataCollection<T extends { name: string }>` (generic type constraint) has nothing to do with `class DataCollection extends Person` (inheritance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several concepts here that are all different although they share some similar syntax.

The standard way to refer to a `type Name = ...` definition is a type alias not a type shape

Firstly types only exist at compile time. So by definition nothing can depend on them at runtime. This means that the type alias `Person` person will not in any way exist in the compiled js.

Classes have a dual nature, their name represents both a type (the instance type of the class) and a runtime value (the constructor function used to initialize the object).

When you say `class DataCollection extends Person` what you mean is that, at **runtime** the class `DataCollection` needs to add to its prototype chain the prototype of `Person`. Since type aliases are erased during compilation, there is nothing for the class `DataCollection` add to its prototype chain making this statement nonsensical for a type alias (or an interface).

When you say `class DataCollection implements Person` you are asking the compiler to make sure that, at compile time, the `class DataCollection` has all the members with the appropriate types of the `Person` type. This is a purely compile time operation so using a type alias is fine here.

The `T` in `class DataCollection<T>` is a generic type parameter. Generic type parameters can be used to make a class reusable for multiple data types while preserving the information about the underlying type:

```
class DataCollection<T> {
    add(value: T) {}
}
var c = new DataCollection<number>();
c.add(1)
c.add("1") // error
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiYBcwGED2IQFNgIJaoDsAeAFQD5oBvAKGjujABNGAKANzBAFdMAuaEgEoqAX2piOAJ2jBoAXmgFMAdziIU6LDnzECXALYAjTJLItBAbmrAAdE1YBGQdbvMWAIgfvhAeh-QTSVRJIA)

Notice above that `T` was never used inside a runtime expression, it is only used in type annotation, we can never use `T` in an expression (ex `new T()` would be invalid). `T` is just there to check at compile time that some aspect of the class (a parameter, a member, a return value) is of a specific type specified when the class is instantiated (in this case `number` specified in `new DataCollection<number>`).

Sometimes we need a bit more information about `T`. For example we might want to have an `onAdded` member. This is where the `DataCollection<T extends TYPE>` comes in. It allows us to constrain `T` to be a sub-type of another specified type:

```
type WithAdd = { onAdd(): void }
class DataCollection<T extends WithAdd> {
    add(value: T) {
        value.onAdd(); // ok since onAdd is on the constraint of T
        value.onAdded(); // error since onAdded is not on the constraint of T
    }
}

class Person {
    name!: string;
    onAdd(): void { }
}
var cErr = new DataCollection<number>(); // error number does not have onAdd
var c = new DataCollection<Person>()
c.add(new Person())
c.add({ onAdd() { } }) // error not a Person
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgQQCaqgXigbygewDs1UAKASgC4oA3fODAXwCgBjAGwEMBnbqAEU7BOAYXzt2EVsDhEAPABUoEAB7AIhVH3hISAPlzMoxqJ3SkandgFcI1BeUMnntK7YB0REhQDcUAPT+BADWUNxwhKzQXuhQcHxEUEjQrETcwABOnBHABABmUApGLsaWNhCexOgQZOR+gcoZGfgZYRFRBFUY8VCE+LmJyVCphOlZOfmFxcYsLGxcvFAAChAZ3Ik4072cALYQAITUYxEA5j5bMbXUdAy4ULPMlq2sAKJNWL0QAO4CQqLikmkskIckI1h2ACNVnpfAEgqtmq0wZDVlBUPgIHw+rlEJwaNEuo9OM8PoRvr9hGIJFIZPIVmsiDDyGx3GYyGSfvT1oQKMzWKzzHhLhQ7ox7o4GgiWr1+qYoJAGYQoEA)

The syntax `DataCollection<T implements { name: string }>` has no meaning in typescript. Since the `extends` in a constraint already deals with just types, there would really be no difference in meaning between saying `T` extends a type or `T` implements type. In both cases `T` would be a subtype of the specified type so having both would be confusing without adding any value. As to why `extends` was chosen over `implements` it's anybody's guess.